# Getting "Error: `output.path` needs to be an absolute path or `/`"

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am new to JS development, in an attempt to hot load changes using webpack-dev-server I keep above exception. The exact stack is:

```
Error: `output.path` needs to be an absolute path or `/`.
at Object.Shared.share.setFs (/Users/mybox/work/day1/ex6/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/lib/Shared.js:88:11)
at Shared (/Users/mybox/work/day1/ex6/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/lib/Shared.js:214:8)
at module.exports (/Users/mybox/work/day1/ex6/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/middleware.js:22:15)
at new Server (/Users/mybox/work/day1/ex6/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js:56:20)

at startDevServer (/Users/mybox/work/day1/ex6/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js:379:12)
at processOptions (/Users/mybox/work/day1/ex6/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js:317:3)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mybox/work/day1/ex6/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js:441:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
```

Here are the webpack config files i have tried already:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./client/app.jsx",
    output: {
        path: "dist/js",
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "http://127.0.0.1:2992/js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.jsx?$/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                include: /client/
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

And:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./client/app.jsx",
    output: {
        path: "/Users/mybox/work/day1/ex6/dist/js",
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "http://127.0.0.1:2992/js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.jsx?$/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                include: /client/,
                query: {
                    presets:['react']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Below is my package.json file

```
{
 "name": "ex6",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
   "server": "node index.js",
   "hot": "webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --port 2992 --progress --colors",
   "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --dev --port 2992 --progress --colors"
 },
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
  "hapi": "^16.1.0",
  "inert": "^4.1.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"babel": "^6.5.2",
"babel-cli": "^6.22.2",
"babel-core": "^6.22.1",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.22.0",
"builder": "^3.2.1",
"webpack": "^2.2.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.3.0"
},
"description": ""
}
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

As the error message says, you need to use absolute path.

To get an absolute path for current directory, You can use [__dirname](http://webpack.github.io/docs/api-in-modules.html#__dirname) to get the current directory and then append `dist/js`. 
So it would be something like,

```
output: {
    path: __dirname + "/dist/js", // or path: path.join(__dirname, "dist/js"),
    filename: "bundle.js"
}
```

Both will work just fine. You can read about webpack configuration [here](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#configuration-object-content)

**Edit**: To use `path: path.join(__dirname, "dist/js")` you will need to require node's built-in `path` module.

Quoting from the docs:

> **Path module**: 
>   It provides utilities for working with file and directory paths. Using it with the prefix __dirname global will prevent file path issues between operating systems and will allow relative paths to work as expected.

You can require it at the top of your `webpack.config.js` as

```
var path = require('path');
.....
....
..
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist/js"),
    filename: "bundle.js"
}
// rest of the configuration
```

Apart from above two methods, You can also use `path.resolve` as mentioned [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-path).

```
path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/js")
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: For some reason i am still getting the same exception with path: "./dist/js", while __dirname + "dist/js" works fine.

Comment: `./dist/js` is relative path. May be that's why you are getting an error. But in my project it's working fine. Which version of webpack you are using?

Comment: webpack": "^2.2.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.3.0"

Comment: Why should this be done? Why does it need a abs path? Is there a specific reason such design decision was made?

Comment: @hungryWolf I don't know about why this design decision was made but it is a limitation and a consistency issue for `webpack` users. We'll soon be able to use the relative path value for `output.path`. You can visit this PR for details: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/6214

Comment: (cont. from hungryWolf's question) In the docs, https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputpath, the absolute path is sill required?

Answer (score 0):

you need to include this at the top of or webpack.config.js file `var path = require('path')`
and then in your path do the following: `path: path.join(__dirname, "dist/js")`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [__dirname](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) to get current executed file's path.

```
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: __dirname + "/src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        filename: 'main.js'
    }
}
```

You could also import build-in [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) API & use resolve method, i think this one is prefer by webpack

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry:  path.resolve("./src/index.js"),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve("./dist"),
        filename: 'main.js'
    }
}
```

Comment: note: `__dirname` only works in CommonJS, i.e. `.cjs`. It doesn't exist in ES6 modules.

Answer (score 0):

It's a design joke called *aymmetric system-inconsistency* from the author, you can find more details from the issue there: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1908.

Answer (score -2):

You can use it like following code to get absolute path.

```
output: {
  path: require('path').resolve("./dist/js"),
  filename: 'bundle.js',
  publicPath: 'http://127.0.0.1:2992/js'
}
```

Comment: don't require in the path. That should be defined at the top of the file so it can be referenced for other paths. That's bad practice.