# - configuration.output.path: The provided value "public" is not an absolute path! with Webpack

Tags: node.js, laravel

I'm using Laravel Mix, that is based on WebPack.

I had it working, and now, it fails with:

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
- configuration.output.path: The provided value "public" is not an absolute path!
```

If I delete my webpack.mix.js content, it still fails the same way.

Can you help me debug this error, I have no clue how to go forward.

I have already deleted the node_modules folder, and ran `npm install`, it is still failing.

Any idea how should I solve this?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Use __dirname

e.g.

```
output: {
    path: __dirname + "/dist/js", // or path: path.join(__dirname, "dist/js"),
    filename: "bundle.js"
}
```

[Getting: Error: `output.path` needs to be an absolute path or `/`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42166492/getting-error-output-path-needs-to-be-an-absolute-path-or)

Comment: `path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist');` // don't forget `const path = require('path');`

Answer (score 19):

Lock webpack to 2.2.1 in composer.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "webpack": "2.2.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^0.8.1",
    ...
}
```

As referenced here:

https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/595

Comment: Not so good solution: lock to an old version should be avoided. Updating laravel mix seems to be a better (wise) solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44282024/978690

Answer (score 7):

Quoting [this comment](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/595#issuecomment-290558852):

> For anyone else wondering how to take advantage of that fix, you can edit your package.json and make sure your larave-mix version is 0.10 or higher:
>
> `"laravel-mix": "^0.10.0",`
>
> Then run npm update.

I think the best (cleanest) solution is to update the Laravel Mix to last version (0.12 today)

Comment: "laravel-mix": "^0.10.0", in package.json saved my day :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a Laravel Mix Incompatibility with Webpack 2.3.0 --> https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/595

Answer (score -1):

Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.output.path: The provided value "public" is not an absolute path!
   -> The output directory as **absolute path** (required).