# Webpack 4 - Output is not creating bundle.js in the correct place

Tags: javascript, webpack

I recently upgraded from Webpack 3 to 4.

Here is my webpack.dev.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'public/bundle.js'
    },
```

**Expected Behaviour**

It should be creating my `bundle.js` in the `public` folder.

**Actual Behaviour**

It's creating a `main.js` file in a folder called `dist`

**Conclusion**

For some reason the output is no longer working as it should.

**Question**

How should I be generating the filename?

Here is the script I run:

```
"scripts": {
    "watch": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --mode development --watch --progress",
},
```

Comment: How do you bundle with webpack? Can you post the script part of your package.json?

Comment: Hi, I've added the script I run to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the doc](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/):

> Out of the box webpack won't require you a configuration file, it will assume the entry point of your project is **src/index** and will output the result in **dist/main.js** minified and optimized for production.
>
> Usually your projects will need to extend this functionality, for this you can create a **webpack.config.js** file in the root folder and webpack will automatically use it.

So, your file is named **webpack.dev.js** so it is not automatically picked up by webpack. You need to specify it in your watch script.

```
"scripts": {
  "watch": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --mode development --watch --progress --config webpack.dev.js",
},
```

You can simplify your watch script by altering your configs like this:

```
// package.json
"scripts": {
  "watch": "webpack --progress --config webpack.dev.js",
},

// webpack.dev.js
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    watch: true,
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work to an extent, it now outputs to `dist/public/bundle.js`.

Comment: I edited my answer, by specifying the `path` parameter. try now.

Comment: Could you modify the answer to be `path: __dirname + 'public',` as without that it throws an error. See issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42940050/

Comment: Indeed, in the hurry I forgot that part. Edited to have the more resilient possibility.