# ##[error]Bash exited with code '1'. When deploying using Pipelines

Tags: azure, npm, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, npm-build

This is my first time deploying something using Pipelines, and it isn't going very well

I've setup my github repo with Pipelines, but my pipeline won't get deployed due to the error stated in the title.

I've attached an image from the build code and error, i honestly have no idea what's going on.

I'd be very appreciative if someone could point me in the right direction and tell me whats causing the issue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qY6FD.png)

Comment: Please share your package.json file and configuration of your task if you still have this issue.

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue? Just a remind of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) .

Answer (score 1):

This error message in the log is the reason why your pipeline failed:`npm ERR! missing script:build`. There are many possible reasons for this error. For example, your package.json file do not have "build" script. Please check your package.json file.

Here is an example of where you would add the script so that you can run a build:

```
{ 
 "name": "Example Application", 
 "version": "1.0.0", 
 "description": "", 
 "main": "index.js", 
 "scripts": { 
    "build": "echo 'build script executed'" 
 }, 
 "author": "", 
 "license": "" 
}
```

You can also refer to [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47343658/using-npm-run-build-fails-with-npm-err-missing-script-build) and check if you have the same issue.