# Invalid configuration object in webpack when setting up CSS Modules

Tags: javascript, json, npm, webpack

I'm getting the following error when trying to set up webpack for CSS Modules...

Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.output.path: The provided value "build" is not an absolute path!
   -> The output directory as **absolute path** (required).

Following are my webpack.config.js and package.json files.

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src',
  output: {
    path: 'build',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "css-modules",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack && open index.html"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.16.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8"
  }
}
```

If anyone could help it would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/42166492/6816939

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "Error: \`output.path\` needs to be an absolute path or \`/\`"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42166492/getting-error-output-path-needs-to-be-an-absolute-path-or)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the absolute path instead of 'build'.

Use `path:  path.join(__dirname, 'build')` instead

Comment: I tried adding this exactly how it's written, but it didn't work... path:  path.join(__dirname, 'build')

Comment: Sorry, the absolute path to where?

Comment: Did you add var path = require('path') at the top of the file?